# How to pass the data through button using unique id in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

i am using django and bootstrap  and i want to pass data through button and show that data on bootstrap popup modal and i want that in each loop x.bots data should be passed uniquely so that i can access bot title ,bot id 
using another loop at x.bots

```
 {% for x in data %}
    <td>{% if x.bots %}<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data="x.bots"> Show Bots &nbsp;{{ x.bots|length }}{% endif %}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

this is my script file

```
<script>
        $(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal', function (event) {
           var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
           var recipient = button.data(x.bots);
           var modal = $(this);
           modal.find('.modal-title').text('Bots Title');
           modal.find('.modal-body input').val(i);
        })
      </script>
```

but i tried alot using different ways but not getting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Use an onclick javascript function and pass the parameters you want to use.

```
    {% for x in data %}
        <td>{% if x.bots %}<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data="x.bots"
                              onclick="myFunction({{ x.bots.title }} , {{ x.bots.id }})"> Show Bots &nbsp;
            {{ x.bots|length }}{% endif %}</a></td>
    {% endfor %}
```

Then in the script implement the javascript function.

```
    function myFunction(title, id) {
        //write code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `var modal = $(this);` will not result in an element since I don't see `this` defined anywhere.

Maybe change it to `var modal = $('#myModal');` or `var modal = event.target`?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 {% for x in data %}
<td>{% if x.bots %}<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data="x.bots"> Show Bots &nbsp;{{ x.bots|length }}{% endif %}</a></td>{% endfor %}
```

To This,

```
{% for x in data %}
<td>{% if x.bots %}<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data="x.bots"> Show Bots &nbsp;{{ x.bots|length }}</a>{% endif %}</td>{% endfor %}
```